# How do I update the imageview inside my listview

Tags: android, view, inflate

I'm making a listview that contains a custom layout. Inside the custom layout is an imageview. When I use Listview lv.setonclick listener it provides me with a variable View that I can use to manipulate the drawable like so.
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

```
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View listview,
                    int position, long arg3) {
                ImageView pincolor = (ImageView) listview
                        .findViewById(R.id.ivimtrackingpin);
           pincolor.setImageResource(R.drawable.pinred);
```

However when I want to make another function I don't have this View listview variable. How do I get it so that I can do the same thing just outside of the onclicklistener? Thanks

EDIT
here is my list view and the adapter

```
SpecialAdapter adapter = new SpecialAdapter(this, list,
                    R.layout.imtracking_row_text, new String[] { "name",
                            "location" }, new int[] { R.id.tvImtrackingName,
                            R.id.tvImtrackingLocation });
HashMap<String, String> temp = new HashMap<String, String>();
                JSONObject user = tracking_users.getJSONObject(i);
                temp.put("name", user.getString("full_name"));
                // upload location time
                temp.put("location", user.getString("last_updated_at"));
                list.add(temp);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);

public class SpecialAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {
    private int[] colors = new int[]{R.drawable.row_background_grey, R.drawable.row_background_white};

    public SpecialAdapter(Context context,
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list, int resource,
            String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, list, resource, from, to);

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        int colorPos = position % colors.length;
        view.setBackgroundResource(colors[colorPos]);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "when I want to make another function"?

Comment: I mean if I want to do the same thing as the onclick version, just not when someone clicks something. Imagine a function called setcolor that only took in a position.

Comment: Ok, I see. I'll put an answer in a sec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find your `ImageView` that way:

```
private ImageView getImageViewAtPosition(ListView listView, int pos) {
    final View      line  = listView.getChildAt(pos); 
    final ImageView image = (ImageView) line.findViewById(R.id.the_id_of_your_image_in_the_xml_layout_of_the_line);

    return image;
}
```

And if you need to know how many entries you have in the list:

```
private int getCount(ListView listView) {
    return listView.getChildCount();
}
```

More details [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildAt%28int%29).

Comment: I just tried this and Im confused about two things. listView.getChildCount() is always 0. It leads me to a source error if I try to do listView.getChildAt(x). My listview is populated with an adapter which I will add above

Comment: Always 0? Well, I've no idea why so far. The way I have described is the way on proceed on my side, but I don't have that 0 problem.

Answer (score 2):

Declare one View globally and assign listview to that view and you can use it anywhere.

Comment: Can you explain this more? I tried adding listview lv to the top but it didn't do anything

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to write your own BaseAdapter subclass or extend whatever ListAdapter implementation you are using and override getView(). There you can inflate the ListView row and do anything necessary to the ImageView.